# Angular UI router conditional autoscroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my Angular application I have a div with `ui-view` that will display a child state. During navigation to one of these states, I would like `autoscroll='true'` to occur, and to the other I'd like `autoscroll='false'` to occur. How can I implement this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could expose `$state` from ui-router in the questionable scope and then do something along

```
autoscroll='$state.in("questionableState")'
```

Comment: Does this work with the execution order of UI-router?

Comment: it is 2-way bound: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/db79d76e5abdb71bbf4baf8d9c3c08ba5ea08d20/src/viewDirective.js#L111

Comment: Thanks - I'm honestly shocked this works as smoothly as it does. Well done!